# StackTraceElement Array's hashcode returns different value each time

Tags: java, arrays, hashcode

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
    String[] sArray = new String[]{"a","b"};
    System.out.println(sArray);
    System.out.println(sArray);
    System.out.println(sArray);
}
```

The above program returns the following output:

```
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@50040f0c
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@2dda6444
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@5e9f23b4
[Ljava.lang.String;@4783da3f
[Ljava.lang.String;@4783da3f
[Ljava.lang.String;@4783da3f
```

Can someone please explain why does `StackTraceElement[]`'s hashcode (the last 8 chars of the `toString()`'s output) return different each time, since the array is not getting changed?

The same is not getting changed for `String[]`.

Comment: Why do you believe the array is not getting changed? `getStackTrace()` returns a ***clone*** of the stacktrace array, so you cannot mess up the array stored inside the exception, which means that every call to `getStackTrace()` returns a different array, hence the different hash code.

Comment: Returning a new array is a standard practice in object-oriented programming known as defensive copying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It creates a new array each time. E.G.

```
public class TestClass{    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }


        System.out.println(new String[]{"a","b"});
        System.out.println(new String[]{"a","b"});
        System.out.println(new String[]{"a","b"});
    }
}
```

While the contents of the array are unchanged, a new array ***object*** is created, and that's what matters to the array `hashCode()` method.

Try this instead to see that the underlying array items are unchanged:

```
    try{
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(Arrays.hashCode(e.getStackTrace()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.hashCode(e.getStackTrace()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.hashCode(e.getStackTrace()));
    }
```